# Cloud9 or WebStorm

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ide

What IDE is better for node.js and/or JQuery development? Which will boost productivity more? What advantages and disadvantages both of them have?

Comment: WebStorm 3.0 is probably one of the best JS editors currently on the market (The only real contender is vs2011).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well one of the clear difference is that Cloud9 is hosted while WebStorm is installed. That means that you can access your Cloud9 and your files anywhere from the cloud, but with WebStorm you have to install it on every computer and get your files from your repo or other. It also means that Cloud9 has a monthly cost, well WebStorm is probably a one-time cost.

Comment: Cloud9 is open source and you can choose to use it hosted as mentioned above, install it on your own remote web server or on your local machine. When using either of the last 2 options, you are not required to pay anything to Cloud9 or be limited in the number of projects you can setup.

Answer (score 1):

Well the next question is are you trying to do node.js or what? What is your ultimate goal? Cloud9 is great for node.js if you want to run it without installing node.js on your local machine. Also, you can hook Cloud9 with Github and deploy your site to Heroku.

If you want just jquery/javascript support, you probably don't need a cloud editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Spket. Although you won't get some cool type hinting out of the box, by using jsdoc you can show the ide what type you are returning of a function. You can also specify as return type the result of execution of another function.
By commenting the function's arguments, you can get the right autocomplete inside the function. BTW spket has a good idea of closures and variables scope.

At least that was an year ago.